# iPhone 5 and 5S Media Query cascading to Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, html, ios, css, iphone

I have the following media query for iPhone 5 and 5S:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

A style in this media query is "cascading" or "leaking" on a Samsung Galaxy S4.

I am not using an actual Samsung Galaxy S4 for testing, instead, I am using Chrome F12 tools **Device Mode**. Device Mode "spoofs" the user agent string and view port for testing different devices.

So perhaps Chrome F12 tools Device Mode has not properly "spoofed" the user agent string and view port so that I can truly test my media queries.

I would think that the `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2` "condition" of my iPhone 5 & 5S media query would eliminate the chance that the iPhone 5 and 5s media query CSS would "leak" to a Samsung Galaxy S4, native or spoofed user agent screen and view port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Galaxy S III has a 2.0 device pixel ratio and the 4 has 3.0 min device pixel ratio so the CSS is correct in its rendering.

SEE [Device Pixel Ratio Reference](http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/)

Comment: I do not follow, my iPhone 5 media query is a min device pixel ratio of 2 and Samsung Galaxy S4 has a min device pixel ratio of 3, so shouldn't the iPhone 5 media query not match the Samsung Galaxy min device ratio of 3?

Comment: Your using a minimum statement meaning the minimum value is 2 plus any value above 2. The S4 is 3 so it qualifies for the css rule. Contrary if the max device pixel ratio was 2 then 2 and anything below 2 would qualify thus eliminating the S4 which is 3.

Comment: ;) I think we're all tired all the time. Anytime, I imagine you're wishing to target retina devices so it may be worth it to couple the declaration with the min-resolution argument to make sure the pixel density is correct for the device.